# How can I do an upgrade(PUT) with One-to-one Relationship using Rest,Jax-rs,jersey and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, rest, jersey, jax-rs

So I having trying this for a while and nothing yet, I was doing a simple CRUD with just one class(Entity) using a tutorial out there, everything was fine and really good, but then I started to complicating a little increasing the number o entity's and using a relationship in this case **ServiceOrdem** has **Client** and **Service** and **Client** has a relationship with **User** and **AccessLevel** , so in this case using Java I think it's very simple and I did a class for tests everything was just fine in the Server side, but I'm having a lot of troubles in the client side so what I'm doing wrong.On case I can properly do a select and see in the client side the informations even delete but I cannot insert new ones or update the fields with relationship in this case my ServiceOrder entity.

**Java Code of my main class for tests(JAVA):**

```
//Updating OrdemDeServico entity.

      //here I select a service(Servico) for his ID then I put the information in an object(serv)
        ServicoDAO sdao = new ServicoDAO();
        Servico serv = sdao.porId(2);
          //here I select a user(User) for his ID then I put the information in an object(usu)
        UsuarioDAO udao = new UsuarioDAO();
        Usuario usu = udao.porId(4);
          //here I select a accessLevel(Nivel) for his ID then I put the information in an object(niv)
        NivelDAO niDAO = new NivelDAO();
        Nivel niv = niDAO.porId(2);
//Then I select the client(Cliente) for his ID put the information in an object(cli) and in the fields with relationship I put the objects that I created before.
        ClienteDAO cliDAO = new ClienteDAO();
        Cliente cli = cliDAO.porId(3);
        cli.setNivel(niv);
        cli.setUsuario(usu);
//Here is where I update the ServiceOrder(OrdemDeServico)entity what I want is to change just the field status the other ones I leave as they are.

        OrdemDeServicoDAO dao = new OrdemDeServicoDAO();
        OrdemDeServico ordem = new OrdemDeServico(2);
        ordem.setStatus(2);
        ordem.setCodServico(serv);
        ordem.setCodCliente(cli);

        dao.atualizar(ordem);
        System.out.println(" " + ordem.getStatus());
```

**Code of one of my resources(I'm showing what I think it's necessary)(JAVA):**

```
@Path("/ordens")

public class OrdemDeServicoResource {
OrdemDeServicoDAO dao = new OrdemDeServicoDAO();

@PUT
@Path("{id}")
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public OrdemDeServico atualizar(OrdemDeServico ordem)throws Exception{
    System.out.println("Atualização de ordem de servico:" +ordem.getStatus());
    dao.atualizar(ordem);
    return ordem;
}

@DELETE @Path("{id}")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
public void remover(@PathParam("id")int id)throws Exception{
    OrdemDeServico ordem = dao.porId(id);
    dao.delete(ordem);

}
```

**Javascript Code for my ServiceOrdemDetails(I think the problem it's here somewhere):**

```
var rootURL ="http://localhost:8080/TCC02/rest";

listOrder();

function listOrder(){
    var id = getId();
    $("#orId").attr("data-value",id);   
    if(id<1){
        alert('id invalido');
        return;
    }
    console.log('getOrder ' +id);
    $.getJSON(rootURL + '/ordens/' + id, function(data){
        if(!data){
            alert('Ordem de servico não encontrada');
            return
        }
    var ordem = data;
    renderDetails(ordem);
    return var oordem = data;   

    });
}

function porIdSer(id3){
    console.log('Find the service for the ID: ' +id3);
    $.getJSON(rootURL + '/servicos/' +  id3, function(data){
        if(!data){
            alert('Service wasn't found');
            return
        }
        var ser = data;
        renderDetailsSer(ser);
        return var sser = data;
    });
}

function porIdLogin(id4){
    console.log('Find the User for the ID: ' +id4);
    $.getJSON(rootURL +'/usuarios/' + id4, function(data){
        if(!data){
            alert('User wasn't found');
            return
        }
        var usu = data;
        renderDetailsUsu(usu);
        return var uusu = data;
    });
}

function porIdLevel(id5){
    console.log('Find the level for the ID: ' + id5);
    $.getJSON(rootURL+ '/niveis/'+ id5,function(data){
        if(!data){
            alert('ID wasn't found');
            return
        }
        var niv = data;
        renderDetailsNiv(niv);  
        return var nniv = data;
    });
}

function porIdCli(id2){
    console.log('Find the cliente for the ID:' + id2);
    $.getJSON(rootURL + '/clientes/' + id2, function(data){
        if(!data){
            alert('Client wasn't found');
            return
        }
        var cli = data;
        renderDetailsCli(cli);
        return var clli = data;
    });
}
    $('#btnAtt').click(function(){
        $("#myModal").modal();
        console.log('Loading details');
        var id = getId();
        if(id<1){
            alert ('Invalid ID');
            return;
        }
        console.log ('getOrdem' + id);
        $.getJSON(rootURL+'/ordens/' + id, function(data){
            if(!data){
                alert('Id wasn't found');
                return
            }
            var ordem = data;
            renderDetails1(ordem);
        });
    });

    $('#btnSave').click(function(){
        updateOrder();
    });

    function updateOrder(){
        var ident = $("#orId").attr("data-value");
        console.log('Update service order' +ident);
        $.ajax({
            type:'PUT',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url:rootURL + '/ordens/' + ident,
            dataType:"json",
            data:formToJSON(),
            success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
                alert('Updated with success');  
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('Something wrong in the updateOrder ' + errorThrown);

            }
        });
    }
    function DeleteOrder(){
        console.log('Delete Service Order');
        $.ajax({
            type:'DELETE',
            url:rootURL + '/' + $('#orId').val(),
            success: function(data, textStatus,jqXHR){
            alert('Order deleted with success');    
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('Error in the delete')
            }       
        });
    }
function getId(){
    //Search and catch the id in the URL
    var id = window.location.hash.substr(1);
    //Confirm if the ID it's a INT
    var intRegex = /^\d+$/;
    return intRegex.test(id)? id : -1;
}
function renderDetails(ordem){
    $('#orId').val(ordem.id);
    $('#nomecliente').val(ordem.codCliente.nome);
    $('#servico').val(ordem.codServico.nomeservico);
    $('#codserv').val(ordem.codServico.id);
    $('#codcli').val(ordem.codCliente.id);
    $('#status').append('<option>' + ordem.status + '</option>');

    //Defining the data-value with the values from codCliente and codServico.
    var atributo2 = ordem.codServico.id;
    $("#codserv").attr("data-value",atributo2);
    var atributo = ordem.codCliente.nivel.id
    $("#codcli").attr("data-value",atributo);

    porIdCli(atributo);
    porIdSer(atributo2);
}

function formToJSON(){
    var orId = $('#orId1').val();
    return JSON.stringify({
        "id": orId == "" ? null : orId,
        "status": $('#status1').val(),
        "servico": $('#servico1').data(),
        "nomecliente":$('#nomecliente1').data(),    
    });
```

This js code it's not complete was very huge but I tried to erase the non useful code with my many crazy tries, so many things are missing but the main code is in here for be analysed, another thing in my **formToJSON** function I did something interesting, I didn't pass the value from two of my fields that has the relationship and the updated works fine of course that the updated wasn't complete and just the field that I entered a value was altered in this case the status field, It works because I din't put the parameter **NOT NULL** in my BD table, so I'm thinking that the problem it's in my **formToJSON** function but I don't know what I have to do. So let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Please send a specific question about some snippet of code and the error trace. We can not analyze your project. What part is not working javascript? java code? insertions? bbdd?

Comment: Okay, so my java code is working just fine, the problem it's in the client side so in my JavaScript ,specifically in my function **updateOrder** that it's not working properly.

Comment: Anyone? I having trying some approaches and nothing yet, this could some kind of resources problem I should add some sub-resources? Or it's just a problem with my UpdateOrder function in JavaScript?